# Simple insert statement not working in php code. Works from MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a simple script which I have included here. the select query works fine but the insert query fails. I am running php, apache and mysql on my macbook.

The table city_profile has ID as a auto increment primary key. And name is a non-null.

```
function testMySQL()    {
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', NULL, 'citee');
  //$query = "select * from city_profile"; //this query works
  $query = "insert into city_profile ('name','state','country') values ('charlotte','north  carolina','usa')"; 
  //whereas the above one fails..
  $results = $db->query($query); 
  if($results)  {
    echo '<p>The query is successful.</p>';
  }else {
    echo '<p>The query is NOT successful.</p>';
  } 

  //close the connection
 $db->close();
}
```

Comment: yes, but only for field names, not for values, or just remove the single quote around field names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change this line:

```
$query = "insert into city_profile ('name','state','country') values ('charlotte','north  carolina','usa')";
```

into this:

```
$query = "insert into `city_profile` (`name`,`state`,`country`) values ('charlotte','north  carolina','usa')";
```